# Install python module and then run python script with .bat file

Tags: python-3.x, batch-file, anaconda

I am trying to run a script on a number of different machines that have Python installed (via the Anaconda distribution) using a `.bat` file.

At the moment, my `.bat` file is as follows:

```
call C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat
call python "[...]\example.py" pause
```

The above works perfectly on my machine, but I know it will not on the ones I'm hoping to run it on.

Say the module I know is missing is `pandasql` and `conda install pandasql` is the command that needs to be run to install it, can I just simply fit it in between the two lines of code above?